# Image is rotated 90 degrees when using clipToMask

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-2d, cgimage

I am trying to clip a portion of an image I take with a camera. Here's my clipping code:

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image {

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask3.png"];
CGImageRef maskImageRef = [maskImage CGImage];

// create a bitmap graphics context the size of the image
CGContextRef mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);


if (mainViewContentContext==NULL)
    return NULL;

CGFloat ratio = 0;

ratio = maskImage.size.width/ image.size.width;

if(ratio * image.size.height < maskImage.size.height) {
    ratio = maskImage.size.height/ image.size.height;
} 

CGRect rect1  = {{0, 0}, {maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height}};
CGRect rect2  = {{-((image.size.width*ratio)-maskImage.size.width)/2 , -((image.size.height*ratio)-maskImage.size.height)/2}, {image.size.width*ratio, image.size.height*ratio}};


CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, rect1, maskImageRef);
CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, rect2, image.CGImage);


// Create CGImageRef of the main view bitmap content, and then
// release that bitmap context
CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(mainViewContentContext);
CGContextRelease(mainViewContentContext);

UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];

CGImageRelease(newImage);

// return the image
return theImage;
```

}

I am calling above method in my captureNow method in my viewcontroller. I am using  AVFoundation to capture still image:

```
-(void) captureNow
{

AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) { break; }
}

NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);



[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {


     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];



     [testImageView setImage:[self maskImage:image]];


     self.firstPieceView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

     self.firstPieceView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   //  self.firstPieceView.image = image;

   //  [firstPieceView setNeedsDisplay];

     NSLog(@"self.firstPiece.frame is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.firstPieceView.frame));
    // [myView becomeFirstResponder];

     }];

self.previewParentView.hidden = YES;
self.photoBtn.hidden=YES;
self.imageMask.hidden = NO;

//add the gesture after taking the first image.
[myView addGestureRecognizersToPiece:self.myView];
```

}

For some reason, my image is always rotated 90 degrees when I clip it. Does anyone know why and how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem, can't seem to figure it to save my life.  Here's the question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307521/ios-png-image-rotated-90-degrees

Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

Here alternative solution to rotate image to 90 degrees ,its code is bellow...

```
yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265/2);
```

when you want to share or save the picture at that time just rotate the Image With 90 Degrees and also if Required then 180 degree....

this is alternate solution if i got any other Idea then i will post again...
hope,this help you...

:)